# Glib equivalent of `textdomain()` and `bindtextdomain()`

Tags: python, internationalization, gettext, glib

I am adding I18N support to some Python code that uses GLib-based interface to the rest of the application. For consistency with the rest of the application I want to use GLib's gettext implementation/wrapper.

I import the GLib API with:

```
import gi
from gi.repository import GLib
```

However, if I see some `*gettext()` functions in the library (`dcgettext`, `dgettext`, `dngettext`, `dpgettext`, `dpgettext2`) I cannot find the equivalent of `textdomain()`and `bindtextdomain()`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GLib doesn't have its own implementation of gettext. It definitely uses it though for translation and -especially on the C side- provides useful wrappers for it.

When using GTK on Python, that means you would normally do to call `bindtextdomain()`: you use the Python-provided `locale` module. If Python was built without gettext support, you'll have to import the `gettext` module

```py
import gettext
import locale

try:
    locale.bindtextdomain(app_id, locale_dir)
    locale.textdomain(app_id)
except AttributeError as e:
    # Python built without gettext support does not have
    # bindtextdomain() and textdomain().
    gettext.bindtextdomain(app_id, locale_dir)
    gettext.textdomain(app_id)
```

Comment: In other words, using Python's `gettext`/`locale` eventually calls the same base code as using GLIB.dgettext() (likely in libgettextlib)?

Comment: Yes, the GLib-provided wrappers [basically do that](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/blob/main/glib/ggettext.c). Sometimes they might sprinkle some extra sanity checks in there, but that's it